# How to filter unique value in REST API

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

I want to filter unique IP regardless it's in DST_Local_IP or in  SRC_Local_IP.
this is my REST API:

```
  {
  "size" : 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
            "match":{"IPV4_DST_ADDR":"120.127.0.0/16"}
        },
        {
            "match":{"IPV4_SRC_ADDR":"120.127.0.0/16"}
        },
        {
          "range" : {
            "LAST_SWITCHED" : {
                "gte" : 0
             }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  },
    "aggs": {
      "DST_Local_IP": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
              "match":{"IPV4_DST_ADDR":"120.127.0.0/16"}
            }
          }
        },
      "aggs": {
         "dst_local_ip" : {
             "terms" : {
                 "field" : "IPV4_DST_ADDR",
                 "size": 10000
              }
            }
         }
      }, 
      "SRC_Local_IP": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
              "match":{"IPV4_SRC_ADDR":"120.127.0.0/16"}
            }
          }
        },
      "aggs": {
         "src_local_ip" : {
             "terms" : {
                 "field" : "IPV4_SRC_ADDR",
                 "size": 10000
              }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

response:

```
"aggregations": {
    "SRC_Local_IP": {
      "doc_count": 48287688,
      "src_local_ip": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "120.127.160.8",
            "doc_count": 6890185
          },
          {
            "key": "120.127.160.77",
            "doc_count": 3791683
          },
          {
            "key": "120.127.160.65",
            "doc_count": 1646648
          },
          {
            "key": "120.127.160.42",
            "doc_count": 1058027
          }
```

.
.
.

```
 "DST_Local_IP": {
      "doc_count": 36696216,
      "dst_local_ip": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "120.127.160.8",
            "doc_count": 2762815
          },
          {
            "key": "120.127.160.99",
            "doc_count": 1344110
          }
```

I want the return value is distinct because the ip in DST_Local_IP may be in SRC_Local_IP duplicated, but I just want the unique ip regardless the ip is in DST_Local_IP or SRC_Local_IP.

How can I do?could you give me some idea:）

thank you in advance!

Comment: What part of this is following REST? `GET /_search` isn't a RESTful API nor does anything in your response look resource-based. Maybe provide more details so your question clearer.

Comment: I have  deleted GET /_search